# RegEx replace character instances based on pattern or seperator

Tags: python, regex, tuples, os.walk

I am just recently learning and utilizing the power of regular expressions
I have a tuple list of files returned from `os.walk()`, like so:

```
files = ('s8_00.tif', 's9_00.tif', 's10_000.tif', 's11_00.tif')
```

I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
files = ('s8_##.tif', 's9_##.tif', 's10_###.tif', 's11_##.tif')
```

I have tried to use this.

```
pad2 = re.compile(r'_00?')

for root, dirs, files in seqDirs:
  pad = files[0]  
  p = pad2.sub("#", pad)
  print p
```

This returns:

```
p = ('s8#.tif', 's9#.tif', 's10#0.tif', 's11#.tif')
```

So I changed the expression around to:

```
pad2 = re.compile('(_)0+')
```

giving me:

```
p = ('s8#.tif', 's9#.tif', 's10#.tif', 's11#.tif')
```

Is the problem in my `p = pad2.sub` function? Or is the problem exist within my compiled expression? Or is it the `"_"` being in the expression that is screwing it up?

I tried even passing some expression inside the `pad2.sub` function just to test it out and of course that didn't really work. I know I am missing something little here and I am a bit stuck.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated along with explanations of logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're going to use a function for the replacement, not a string.

```
def replacer(data):
    return re.sub(r'(?<=_)(0+)', lambda m: m.group(0).replace('0', '#'), data)

files = ('s8_000.tif', 's9_00.tif', 's10_000.tif', 's11_00.tif')
map(replacer, files)
print(files)
```

`?<=` is a *positive lookbehind assertion*. You can find an explanation in the docs at [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

`0+` captures all following zeros

The lambda function replaces every `0` with the `#`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much, this is definitely a cool function. I can see the extensibility of this which is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it where any number could be there, make your regex be

`pattern = re.compile("_(\d+)")`

and do the substitution by

`pattern.sub("_"+len("\g<1>")*"#", filename)`

In any regex you can access what was caught with the parens with "\g<1>" for the first value, "\g<2>" for the next set of parens and so on. "\d+" is going to get any digit character in the expression. If you very specifically just want to look for zeros, you could replace it with "_(0+)"

Comment: Then what does he do if he doesn't know how many numerics he wants to replace?

Comment: @BostonJohn I understand I can be very literal and replace characters in that way. but the files sometimes have 3 or more zeros then this would fail to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off finding the matches, calculating the length of them, and then replacing them with that number of `#`s.

Comment: this gives me

    "raise error, v # invalid expression
    sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat"

I think I will try something out with your second suggestion though.

Comment: @J.A.M yeah, I guess you can't have variable length lookbehinds in python. That's dumb.

Comment: @J.A.M look at the top answer -- it does exactly what I was talking about/would have done